# FireBug data transfer size

Tags: firefox, web, firebug, gzip

FireBug when using the Net panel to monitor files being transfered from a site, the total size of the data transfered is given at the bottom of the list. Does this figure reflect the size of the data coming across the wire or the total size of the files after gzip/zlib decompression.

Comment: It reflects the size of the requested data.

Answer (score 5):

If the contents are gzipped, it shows the size of the compressed files. So it's the real network data size.

Answer (score 0):

From [Firebug's Wiki](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel):

> ... there is a summary at the bottom of the Request List.
>   This summary contains info about the total number of requests, the
>   total file size and the total page load time.

In the request list, each entry presents the details of the request, where the Size column displays the size of the received response. So, the total file size in the bottom displays the sum of the sizes of all the responses.

Comment: To the downvoter, could you please tell me why did you downvote the answer?

Comment: Thanks bacchus. You have my upvote. Don't know why someone would down vote you there.

Comment: Maybe because you didn't answer the question, which was specifically about whether the size was before or after compression.